# Storing Raw HTML Files in Solr

Tags: html, apache, indexing, solr, apache-tika

I have Solr 5.4.1 and I am trying to index and store html files. I would like to store the raw HTML so that I can use it for highlighting.

Is there any way to do this? My update/extract request handler uses Tika, which I believe is stripping the html tags from my files and so would like to avoid this for storing the raw html content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solr is not that great for data retrieval. Have you considered storing the raw html in another place, such as a sql database or another rdbms? Only put the searchable text in Solr, then add a page id to the solr document, and then look up the full html via page id in your db.

Comment: The main issue is that I want to search for keywords and then highlight these keywords in the raw html. Is this possible?
For example. <div>Hello there this is some keyword content</div> and then if I was to search for "keyword" Solr would output
<div> Hello there this is some <em>keyword</em> content </div> or something similar.

Comment: Solr can't do dynamic insertion of html tags anyways, right? Wouldn't you grab the resulting raw HTML from your db and then do a search for the keyword after the fact and insert the html there?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to search HTML content in Solr is to index using the HTMLStripCharFilterFactory. This strips HTML tags (including attributes) from the text at index time, meaning you can search the text without also searching the tags. The stored version of the field will still have the HTML tags included.

```
<!-- Field type for HTML fields, stripping HTML characters during indexing -->
<fieldType name="text_html" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

However, this can result in the highlighting markup causing your HTML tags to break, either by appearing in the middle of HTML tags, or cutting out closing tags. An alternative solution to this is to strip the HTML before storing in Solr.